# Validating method arguments for nil

Tags: ruby, validation, null

I show a Java method with validations following method declaration:

```
public Integer executeComputation(Integer a, Integer b) {
   Validate.notNull(a);
   Validate.notNull(b);
   Validate.isTrue(b != 0);
   return a/b;
}
```

Is it a good practice to translate this method call to ruby code as following:

```
def execute_computation(a,b)
  raise 'a is nil' if a.nil?
  raise 'b is nil' if b.nil?
  raise 'zero division' if b == 0
  a/b
end
```

This is a trivial example, but I feel that for Ruby it is too talkative. Yet I'm used to checking my parameters in public methods in Java to prevent some hard-to-find NPEs deep.

Can somebody explain how argument validations in Ruby work? Ideally some reference to literature.

Comment: Do you really catch those exceptions you raise? Otherwise you might as well wait for the Runtime Exception when `a` or `b` is `nil` or `b` is zero.

Comment: @zwippie True, but this shows exact place of the problem (bad method argument) otherwise those arguments (a and b in this case) can be used in another method call and NPE can show itself somewhere much deeper in the stack trace, making finding a problem harder.

Answer (score 1):

Better fail fast. Check types only if you have some strong restrictions that you want to satisfy. Besides Runtime exceptions will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is a duck typed language. Java isn't. [Confident Ruby](http://www.confidentruby.com/) code doesn't ever check for types of arguments. If you have to check types, it's a smell. Validation should be on the value and not on the type.

How about handing runtime exceptions `NoMethodError: undefined method '/' for nil:NilClass` and/or `TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum` and/or `ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0`?

Comment: To put it more bluntly: writing Ruby like Java defeats the point of using Ruby.

Comment: @Chirantan Hi, you misunderstood my question. I was not asking about type checking. And I'm not trying to merely translate runtime exceptions into my own. Reason why you are checking parameters of public (client accessible) methods is that you don't want to see those native runtime exceptions (NoMethodError, TypeError) somewhere deep in your library. You want to see them in a place where they were caused. In this case it is invalid method call. Thank for a book reference, can you point on a chapter?

Answer (score 1):

If you feel you need to do value validation and that's too talkative, use a module that makes it less talkative, like your commons module did.

```
module Validate
  def self.not_zero val
    raise ArgumentError, 'arg is zero' if val == 0 
  end
end

def execute_computation(a,b)
  Validate.not_zero b
  a/b
end
```